# General solutions of various PDEs

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm a graduate student of engineering, struggling for math. I need to know the general solutions to some PDEs such as

The elastodynamic equation in frequency domain;
$$\nabla\cdot\sigma(x) + \rho_{s}\omega^{2}\vec{u}(x) = 0$$
or, Helmholtz equation;
$$(\nabla^{2} + k^{2})p(x) = 0$$
in polar (or spherical) coordinate especially for $0\le r\le R$ or $R\le r \le\infty$ with second boundary condition ($\partial_{r}u=f(\theta)\ne0$, etc.)

For example, I know that of Laplace equation for $R\le r\le\infty$ with $\partial_{r}u=f(\theta)$ is given by:
$$u(r,\theta)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R}{n}\left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^{n}\left(a_{n}\cos{n\theta}+b_{n}\sin{n\theta}\right)$$

Where can I find these type of expression for solutions to PDEs?

Comment: The example solution that you give for the Laplace eqn is a Fourier series. These are valid and useful for linear pdes. Just sub in the formula to your eqn and boundary conditions.